# Is Spring Cloud Dataflow local server able to be distributed?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been using SCDF for a while, and realise the main diffs between XD and SCDF is XD is born to be distributed, but SCDF seems work like a platform for SC stream apps. At least local server works like so.

So my question is, is it possible that scdf local server being distributed? I see no trends on local server being distributed.

Any idea on this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you might have known already, the `local` server is not intended for `production` deployments and for the `development` purpose only.
The `local` SCDF server is not intended to have distributed use case as there is no co-ordination service for the number of local servers running. But all the apps deployed by the `local` server run as separate processes.